# attachment property in several models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am using ASP.NET MVC + LinqToSQL.

There is attachment model in my application. I need `<IEnumerate>Attachment Attachments` in several models. I don't wasn't to create different attachment models for different parent classes. Is there simple way to do it?

Comment: I assume you mean the rails acts-as-attachment sort of attachment? You may wish to edit your question to reflect specifically file attachment if that is what you intend?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to use attachments in more places in your model? For example for `Employee` and for `Customer` objects? Do you mean something like:

```
public class Attachment { /* Various properties... */ }
public class Attachments : List<Attachment>
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        foreach (Attachment attachment in this)
            DoSomethingToAttachment(attachment);
    }
}
public interface IAttachmentHandler
{
    void HandleAttachments();
}
public class Employee : IAttachmentHandler
{
    private Attachments _attachments;
    public void HandleAttachments()
    {
        _attachments.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class Customer : IAttachmentHandler
{
    private Attachments _attachments;
    public void HandleAttachments()
    {
        _attachments.DoSomething();
    }
}
```